# d3.js linkStrength influence on linkDistance in a force graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on a graph to show relations between different nodes. The closer related the nodes are (according to business logic), the closer together the nodes should be.

I noticed that some links with the `linkStrength` of `.1` are *shorter* (that is what I wanted to achieve) and some others with the same strength are *longer* than the ones with the `linkStength` of `1`. From a documentation about the force layout parameters I now found this quote:

> The default linkStrength value is 1.0, which maintains the full effect of linkDistance. By setting the value of linkStrength less than 1, though, the distance constraint can be relaxed.

Does that mean that if I was to set `linkDistance` to `150`, the links with `linkStrength(1.0)` will be closer to 150 than the ones with `linkStrength(.1)`? And if yes, do they need to be shorter, longer or doesn't that matter at all? Because I was kind of surprised about the layout.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if your statement about the distance is true, but i am inclined to say yes. I am sure though that when the linkStrength gets smaller, the edges are effected more by the charge of the nodes and the "gravity" of the forcechart. The nodes attract or repulse each other, based on their charge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To cut a long story short: when using D3's force layout there is no built-in way to enforce a fixed length of the links. The force layout is inherently dynamic and setting values for [force.linkDistance()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance) and [force.linkStrength()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkStrength) introduces just another force to the set of calculations carried out on each iteration, i.e. each *tick*, while the force layout is running.

There are three forces calculated on each [tick](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/fd7c000db41db4976c61f488bad7fac89c607014/src/layout/force.js#L59):

**1. [Link length](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/fd7c000db41db4976c61f488bad7fac89c607014/src/layout/force.js#L79-L95).** The first force to be calculated is the adjustment for link lengths set via the above mentioned methods. This is done in a loop for each link and, looking at the source, this comes down to essentially [one line](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/fd7c000db41db4976c61f488bad7fac89c607014/src/layout/force.js#L87) of code:

```
l = alpha * strengths[i] * ((l = Math.sqrt(l)) - distances[i]) / l;
```

With `l` calculated to be the Euclidean distance between the link's source node and target node, the desired link distance `distances[i]` and the link's `strengths[i]` this line determines how to pull both nodes together or push them apart to approximate the link distance set via `force.linkDistance()`. It's easy to see, that the link strength has a linear effect on the resulting force. Contrary to the API documentation, though, which defines the valid range for the strength to be in the interval *[0,1]*, the source code does not impose any restrictions on the value set by `force.linkStrength()`.

**2. [Gravity](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/fd7c000db41db4976c61f488bad7fac89c607014/src/layout/force.js#L97-L106).** The second force to be calculated will take into account [gravitational forces](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#gravity) on each node.

**3. [Charge](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/fd7c000db41db4976c61f488bad7fac89c607014/src/layout/force.js#L108-L116).** Lastly, the mutual forces of the nodes' [charges](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#charge) are calculated.

Because the effects of all the calculated forces are superimposed and will add up to the resulting movement of each node for a given tick, it becomes clear, that the link length is only one part of the entire computation. The other two forces may weaken or even reverse its effect.

As for your question

> Does that mean that if I was to set linkDistance to 150, the links with linkStrength(1.0) will be closer to 150 than the ones with linkStrength(.1)?

The outcome depends largely on the setup of the force layout's parameters and the distribution of the nodes, and still no guarantee is made regarding the final lengths of the links.

Answer (score 2):

The link strength sets the rigidity of the links, not the distance between the nodes ([force layout doc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout)). The distance of the nodes from each other is controlled by their charge. You can make the charge of a node dynamic like so:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .theta(0.1)
        .charge(function (d) {
            return -(d.radius * d.radius * 0.125);
        })
        .gravity(0.1)
        .size([width, height])
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
```

A working example that uses this technique: [vizz.ly](http://vizz.ly/blog/traffic_deaths.php)

Comment: could you update this syntax for v4? I have a related question here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244186/how-do-you-set-a-fixed-link-distance-with-d3-v4?noredirect=1#comment65826858_39244186