# how do you set a fixed link distance with d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

All the API examples seem to be for v3 still.
I'm trying to understand how to create a force graph with links of a fixed distance, like:
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278

I looked at link_distance but not sure how to apply it:
https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_distance

Creating a graph like this:

```
  let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-150))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

I tried various combos like:

```
  // .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(20).strength(1))
  // .force("linkDistance", 20)
  // .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
```

but no luck!

So it seems link_distance can't be fixed? 
its a result of strength and (distance, whatever that is)

So how do I apply `strength` and `distance` to links in d3 v4 ?
Is it applied to the simulation or something else?

Comment: There is no such thing as a fixed link distance for neither D3 v3 nor v4. Have a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34376334/4235784) to [*"d3.js linkStrength influence on linkDistance in a force graph"*](/q/34355120) for an explanation for v3. Although much has changed, especially for the force layout, this same principle holds true for v4 as well. If the links appear to have equal length, this is by chance and mostly influenced by the other parameters and forces around.

Comment: OK thanks. but I'm still unclear how to set the linkDistance or linkStrength commands with the v4 API. Do i set those on the `d3.forceSimulation` or some other thing?

Comment: Yes, it was a bit of a challenge looking for v4 vs. v3. I would recommend two things: 1) V4-only searching on http://blockbuilder.org/search#d3version=v4 (I didn't find this until late). 2) My non-trivial d3 force graph: http://bl.ocks.org/bill-mybiz/dfe5b70ad9b469e23b8820790fa53109 . I made this for a non-trivial reference implementation since it was a bit frustrating to keep coming across v3 documentation. That has a dynamic add/remove nodes using node groups (not just simple circles), es6 class structure, and more. It includes setting the distance, as well as a bunch of other settings.

Answer (score 26):

You are closer to change the distance in v4! Check this change... it works for me:

```
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d, i) { return i; }).distance(100).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

The original code was almost correct. However, the `i` needs to be added to the function, and `i` also needs to be returned in order to change the link distance. I edited the original code to reflect this. Please see this link: [Link to Free Code Camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/trouble-converting-this-d3-to-version-4/46618)

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there... check this out, this code works for me..

Note: I'm getting length of links dynamically based on node labels with this code ***GetNodeDefaults(d.label).linkDistance*** i.e, it can be 100 or 200 or 300 etc.,

```
var forceLink = d3
    .forceLink().id(function (d) {
        return d.id;
    })
    .distance(function (d) {
        return GetNodeDefaults(d.label).linkDistance;
    })
    .strength(0.1);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", forceLink)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(function (d, i) {
        var a = i == 0 ? -2000 : -1000;
        return a;
    }).distanceMin(200).distanceMax(1000))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(0.01))
    .force("x", d3.forceX(0.01))
    .on("tick", ticked);
```

Answer (score -1):

you may try without `force('center')`

```
let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-150));
```